# ExtJS 4 - After using grid.reconfigure, load mask does not display

Tags: javascript, grid, extjs4, loadmask

I'm using the `reconfigure` method of `Ext.grid.Panel` to switch between two stores in a grid.  The load mask on the initial store works correctly, but no load mask is displayed for the second store.

See jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Esfu4/

When you hit the button to switch to Store 2, no load mask appears, even when you refresh afterwards.

If you look at the jsFiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/H8U3E/), where the two stores are reversed, the load mask works correctly.

Trying to figure out how to get the load mask to work in the first jsFiddle.

Comment: It's a bug in 4.1; 4.2 no longer has this behavior.

Comment: That's incorrect - I'm using 4.2.1.  See the external resources in my jsFiddle links

Comment: Huh, could have sworn I saw it working somewhere. This looks related: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?263185